# Sending objects on websockets

Tags: javascript, websocket

I define an object like this:

```
function Receipt (stat, pr) {
    var status = stat,
        price = pr;
    this.somefunction = function (someArgs) {
        // do something
    }            
}
```

And then I have a websocket and send this object;
The websocket is connected to a server which then relays the message to all other clients.

```
var rec = new Receipt('NEW', 10);
socket.send({obj: rec});
```

The problem is this: when I receive the data on the other client(s), I receive empty objects. Is there a way to serialise the data and send it so that I can duplicate the object on the other clients – so that the definition of the object remains the same? I've tried `JSON.stringify` which hasn't helped, it just gives me `"{}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the object to hold on to the initial values of `stat` and `pr`, you need to  store them in `this`.

In the code you provided, the only property of `rec` is `somefunction` which won't get stringified because it's a function.

```
function Receipt (stat, pr) {
    this.status = stat;
    this.price = pr;
    this.somefunction = function (someArgs) {
        // do something
    }
}

var rec = new Receipt('NEW', 10);
JSON.stringify(rec)
// returns "{"status":"NEW","price":10}"
```

Comment: But what if I don't want status and price to be exposed?

Comment: Then your object has no stringifiable properties. JSON doesn't include functions. You could create a `toJSON` function that returns only the properties you want included, but generally in JavaScript, you don't worry about what's private or public. The convention is to name private variables with a leading underscore.